# Is it possible to split "not" and "always" in a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Could someone please help me understand why "not always" is grouped in the examples below? What grammatical rule is being broken by splitting them?

1. Not the cheapest options are always available - sounds incorrect
2. It is not always the cheapest options that are available - sounds correct
3. The cheapest options are not always available - sounds correct

Comment: You can modify your first sentence to make it correct: 
**It is not the cheapest options that are always available.**

Comment: For your *exact* context it's hard (though maybe not *impossible*) to draw a semantic distinction between #2 and #3. But consider the same basic constructions in (a) *It is not always learners who post questions on ELU* and (b) *Learners do not always post questions on ELU*, which have significantly different meanings.  Whatever - I think this question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not ELU.

Comment: I think that this question is on topic. The OP knows there is something wrong with 1, and is asking for a grammatical 'diagnosis', as it were. My impression is that such questions about grammar are on topic for ELU. The only objection might be that the OP didn't report on any attempts to find out the answer from widely available sources.

Comment: Of course it's possible to split "not" and "always" and how does that matter in - or even relate to - yur Question, please? 

Sorry to say, it looks as though all your examples are constructs, not quotations.

Do you insist that any of them is a quotation or what, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with 1. is that you are trying to directly negate an adjective which is being used atributively. Namely, you are trying to directly use *not* to negate the adjective *cheap* (in its superlative form), which is here functioning as an attributive modifier of the noun *options*.

When the adjective is used either predicatively (as in [1] a. below) or postpositively  ([1] b.) rather than attributively, such direct negation is OK:

[1] a. *Our dryers are n͟o͟t͟ ͟t͟h͟e͟ ͟c͟h͟e͟a͟p͟e͟s͟t͟.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GiZBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA71&dq=%22not%20the%20cheapest%22&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q=%22not%20the%20cheapest%22&f=false)
      b. *There seemed to always be s͟o͟m͟e͟o͟n͟e͟ ͟n͟o͟t͟ ͟h͟a͟p͟p͟y͟ about something.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ntnYAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA104&dq=%22someone%20not%20happy%22&pg=PA104#v=onepage&q=%22someone%20not%20happy%22&f=false)

According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 809),

> In general, attributive adjectives cannot be negated directly by *not*: cf. **a not large house* or **It looked not large*.

An exception is illustrated in

*Not inexpensive options are always available.*

Here is again CGEL (pp. 809-810):

> ***Not unattractive*: *not* with affixally negated adjectives**
>
> [10]   i *Morton was in his early fifties and n͟o͟t͟ ͟u͟n͟a͟t͟t͟r͟a͟c͟t͟i͟v͟e͟ ͟t͟o͟ ͟w͟o͟m͟e͟n͟.*
>  
>            ii *It was a n͟o͟t͟ ͟u͟n͟d͟i͟s͟t͟i͟n͟g͟u͟i͟s͟h͟e͟d͟ private university with a large endowment.*
>  
>           iii *They had fixed the walls, and purchased some n͟o͟t͟ ͟i͟n͟e͟l͟e͟g͟a͟n͟t͟ furniture.*
>
> ... The *not* + adjective construction illustrated in [10] is permitted only when the adjective consists of a base preceded by a productive and transparently negative prefix. Note then that we cannot have **a not anarchic society*, **several not intrepid explorers*: *anarchic* and *intrepid* are etymologically divisible into negative prefix + base, but this analysis is not synchronically transparent. [A subtle point here derives from the fact there are adjectives treated as affixally negated by some speakers and not by others. For example, *impious* is pronounced /ɪmˈpaɪəs/ by some, making it clear that it is analysable into negative prefix + *pious*; but others pronounce it as /ˈɪmpiəs/, not related in pronunciation to *pious*. In general, <sup>%</sup>*a not impious man is acceptable* for the first group of speakers, but not for the second.] A further condition is that the adjective must be gradable. This excludes examples like **a not immoral purpose*, **this not uncrystalline substance*, or **a not illegal act*. In these uses the adjectives are classificatory rather than gradable: purposes are either moral or not, substances either form crystals or they do not, acts are either legal or not.
>
> There has been occasional prescriptive condemnation of the '*not un-*' construction, though most manuals are perfectly clear in their view that it is fully acceptable.